# mysql random from top 10

Tags: php, mysql

I have the mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM bigtable WHERE column1='1' ORDER BY column2 DESC LIMIT 10
```

And then I put everything in an array and use php to choose a random row from this array of 10 items.

Is there a way to do this with a single mysql query instead of mysql+php part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After take top 10, then take 1 with random:

```
SELECT * from (
   SELECT * FROM bigtable 
   WHERE column1='1' 
   ORDER BY column2 DESC LIMIT 10
) T ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: T is to name the temporary table created by the select statement. It could be any name, but the table must be named.

Comment: T is a table alias, but in this query table is replaced by a query.

Comment: @David19801 T is a table alias

Comment: Ok, remember to create index over bigtable(column1, column2 Desc) for best performance.

Comment: @cheeken, of course. David you should test also cheeken approach before set this answer as solution.